# JSON to HTML table or div using PHP

Tags: php, json, html-table

I am getting some JSON response from an API, I want to display this response into an HTML Table or DIV. I have decoded the response using the following line:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

And I am getting the following output in the `$data` variable. I need help with displaying the following response into a table, please suggest.

```
stdClass Object (
    [response] => stdClass Object (
    [result] => stdClass Object (
        [Leads] => stdClass Object (
            [row] => array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [no] => 1
    [FL] => array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [val] => LEADID
    [content] => 1852733000019035100
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [val] => SMOWNERID
    [content] => 1852733000016827001
    )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please take a moment and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first? Maybe we can give you a proper answer if your question will be more detailed.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @fabrik I got it solved with the following script: 
`<tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($data->response->result->Leads->row as $row) {
                    $columns = 0;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach ($row->FL as $fl) {
                        echo '<td class="value">';
                        echo $fl->content;
                        echo '</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
            </tbody> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code does the magic for me, posting just in case it helps anyone else with the same JSON structure.

```
<tbody>
<?php
            foreach ($data->response->result->Leads->row as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach ($row->FL as $fl) {
                    echo '<td class="value">';
                    echo $fl->content;
                    echo '</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
</tbody>
```